# Django - use redirect view with multiple parameters

Tags: django, django-views

Im trying to redirect to a view with multiple parameters:

in my urls.py (app exhibition) I have:

```
path('map/<float:lat>/<float:lng>/<int:zoom>', views.MapView.as_view(), name='map')
```

where float is defined in a path converter like this:

```
'[-+]?\d*\.?\d*'
```

For the redirection I have:

```
return redirect('exhibition:map', lat=48.128365,long=11.5662713,zoom=3)
```

After hours of trying and researching similar questions I still get:

```
Reverse for 'map' with keyword arguments '{'lat': 48.128365, 'long': 11.5662713, 'zoom': 3}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['de/map\\/(?P<lat>[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d*)\\/(?P<lng>[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d*)\\/(?P<zoom>[0-9]+)$']
```

If I adjust the url pattern and the redirect call to a single pattern (be it float or int) the redirection works. Thus the problem should be related to my usage of multiple parameters - but I just can see what is wrong.
Any hints welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess it's typo, you have defined `lng` as second parameter in your `path` but in `redirect` statement you call it `long`, it should be

```
return redirect('exhibition:map', lat=48.128365, lng=11.5662713, zoom=3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much cizario - so helpful to have another pair of eyes look on that. I was investigating all kinds of approaches but never saw the typo!